# mount a ntfs windows harddrive permanently at startup

Tags: ntfs, fstab, automount

I need some help when mounting a windows hard drive permanently at startup. As far as I red the documentation, I need to add a line in fstab
So far I got the Info  -- sudo blkid --- terminal

```
/dev/sdc5: LABEL="DatenWin" UUID="61EDA0796D906D67" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="13a0e5c8-80bd-4664-a32f-321dd3162e83"
```

Is there anybody out there who can tell me how I modify the following line, I picked up in the documentation for my fstab?

```
/dev/sdc5 /media/DatenWin ntfs uid=1000,umask=0022 0 0
```

---

maybe its already enough...

Answer (score 0):

Open fstab to edit:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line:

```
UUID=61EDA0796D906D67 /media/DatenWin  ntfs  defaults,fmask=133,dmask=022,gid=1000,uid=1000  0  0
```

Also:
You will need to make the directory DatenWin first:

```
sudo mkdir /media/DatenWin
```

And enter the following commands into a terminal to confirm that the uid:

```
id -u {yourusername}
```

and gid are correct:

```
id -g {yourusername}
```

Then reboot. You shlould have the drive mounted and have sane permissions that match your home folder.

Comment: Thanks a big help I placed the above line into fstab and made the directory and the HD appears and is writable, but where do I have to confirm the uid and gid?

Comment: Sorry, you would enter those commands into a terminal same as the gedit and mkdir commands.

Comment: thanks, I have to say sorry lol I'm the beginner...teh terminal returns "1000" thats all

Comment: No worries, you'll see the fstab entry I wrote used 1000 for uid and gid. If the id command returned 1000 for both then you can use my code as is. I understand 1000 to be the default needed but the commands I gave you were just so you could confirm.